# Systemd - restart service if it is activating too long

Tags: systemd, services, timeout

I have a systemd service and some ExecStartPost scripts. Sometimes these scripts may take a long time. While these scripts are executing, service is in "activating" state. 
Is there any way to set an activation timeout? E.g. if service is activating more than a minute, restart the service.

Any sugestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeoutStartSec` parameter of systemd service Unit solves the problem